# SSH client can not connect inside the docker container

Tags: ssh, docker, sshd, ssh-keys

Having issues connecting from my docker container to a web server in the cloud where I can connect using my macOs terminal but not from the docker exec terminal.

Steps

1.I have created a docker container from a docker image of Ubuntu 16.4.

2.I have copied the files from my mac to Docker container using docker copy command to my container.

3.When I am trying to connect to my web server I am getting permission denied error.

Here is the detailed log

```
# ssh 35.205.237.237 -vvvv
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "35.205.237.237" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 35.205.237.237 [35.205.237.237] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.5p1 Ubuntu-10ubuntu0.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.5p1 Ubuntu-10ubuntu0.1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to 35.205.237.237:22 as 'root'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/root/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /root/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 35.205.237.237
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:jcQCtUn0MIkgQTFUpEwbWbXtM80JxJ+M3Kxr6N4/El4
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/root/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /root/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 35.205.237.237
debug1: Host '35.205.237.237' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil))
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: no such identity: /root/.ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /root/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

On the server side

```
rifaterdemsahin@webserver:~$ tac /var/log/auth.log  | less

Mar 10 17:27:52 webserver sshd[23208]: Connection closed by authenticating user root 139.162.201.187 port 55184 [preauth]
Mar 10 17:27:52 webserver sshd[23208]: Failed publickey for root from 139.162.201.187 port 55184 ssh2: RSA SHA256:jFphYy2a+fTHHMP0zbV83yPsLoB67ULn+/VLPBAwXr4
Mar 10 17:27:52 webserver sshd[23208]: Connection from 139.162.201.187 port 55184 on 10.132.0.2 port 22
Mar 10 17:25:55 webserver sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Mar 10 17:25:55 webserver sshd[23193]: Server listening on :: port 22.
Mar 10 17:25:55 webserver sshd[23193]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Mar 10 17:25:54 webserver sshd[1232]: Received signal 15; terminating.
Mar 10 17:25:54 webserver sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by rifaterdemsahin(uid=0)
Mar 10 17:25:54 webserver sudo: rifaterdemsahin : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/rifaterdemsahin ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/service ssh restart
```

The files are there

[image]

Inside the file

[image]

On the server side, I see these in auth log

```
Mar 10 18:59:39 webserver sshd[24041]: Connection closed by authenticating user rifaterdemsahin 139.162.201.187 port 44722 [preauth]
Mar 10 18:59:58 webserver sshd[24048]: Connection from 139.162.201.187 port 44804 on 10.132.0.2 port 22
Mar 10 19:01:43 webserver sshd[24048]: Connection closed by authenticating user rifaterdemsahin 139.162.201.187 port 44804 [preauth]
Mar 10 19:02:41 webserver sshd[24067]: Connection from 139.162.201.187 port 45734 on 10.132.0.2 port 22
```

I can login from my Mac Book Pro Terminal

```
Erdems-MacBook-Pro:.ssh rifaterdemsahin$ ssh -i id_rsa 35.205.237.237
Enter passphrase for key 'id_rsa': 
Last login: Sat Mar 10 18:03:24 2018 from 139.162.201.187
rifaterdemsahin@webserver:~$
```

Comment: `ssh` didn't find any ssh keys to offer to the server. How are you expecting ssh to authenticate to the server? What specific key file is it supposed to use?

Comment: the files are there added the screenshot

Comment: Are you really intending to attempt login to the remote as the root user? Try `ssh user@host`

Comment: ssh rifaterdemsahin@35.205.237.237
Enter passphrase for key '/root/.ssh/id_rsa':
Permission denied (publickey).   debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1

Comment: Does `ssh-keygen -yef ~/.ssh/id_rsa` succeed?

Comment: Does `strace -eopen ssh user@host` show anything interesting? e.g: `open("/root/.ssh/id_rsa", O_RDONLY) = 4` or `... = -1`

Comment: # ssh-keygen -yef ~/.ssh/id_rsa
Enter passphrase:
---- BEGIN SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
Comment: "2048-bit RSA, converted by root@a5e3e8df46cf from OpenSSH"
AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDNdQ+kB1h9E+eG4RMvPWjT/dJRgVKy683CCsuV35
c6m/mMzzah0bFhTGqxla+U72ld7C1BLDzONiC6+jjqa720p//i0st3+FU8u+X9Xtly/0FL

Comment: # strace -eopen ssh rifaterdemsahin@35.205.237.237
strace: ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, ...): Operation not permitted
+++ exited with 1 +++

Comment: On the server side I also see these from my own ip. Mar 10 18:59:39 webserver sshd[24041]: Connection closed by authenticating user rifaterdemsahin 139.162.201.187 port 44722 [preauth]
Mar 10 18:59:58 webserver sshd[24048]: Connection from 139.162.201.187 port 44804 on 10.132.0.2 port 22
Mar 10 19:01:43 webserver sshd[24048]: Connection closed by authenticating user rifaterdemsahin 139.162.201.187 port 44804 [preauth]
Mar 10 19:02:41 webserver sshd[24067]: Connection from 139.162.201.187 port 45734 on 10.132.0.2 port 22

Comment: Please temporarily run your docker container with `--privileded` and try `strace` again...

Comment: hmmm it says. The authenticity of host '35.205.237.237 (35.205.237.237)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:jcQCtUn0MIkgQTFUpEwbWbXtM80JxJ+M3Kxr6N4/El4.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
open("/root/.ssh/known_hosts", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_APPEND, 0666) = 4
Warning: Permanently added '35.205.237.237' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
+++ exited with 255 +++

Comment: Attie after running it in --privileded mode it is solved. I copied the keys. As I restart the container the keys where lost. Even though when I write whoamI it says root. But does not have the access than... Please answer it so I can mark it answered

Comment: I'm not sure what the answer is... it's certainly not to run the container with `--privileged` [just noticed my previous typo - apologies]

Comment: i restarted the container copied the keys with docker copy than removed a config file than it started working.